# MSVCR110.dll is missing wamp can't start although MSVCR package is intalled

Tags: wamp, msvcr100.dll

i am facing this problem and i don't know how to fix it.i have installed VCR 2010, VCR 2012, VCR 2013 and VCR 2010 (x86) on my machine but still when i want to start WAMP it gives me this message MSVCR110.dll is missing.

This snip shot is from my window control panel as you can see i have installed VCR packages.

[image: Control panel snip shot]

This is the message when i want to run WAMP
[image: VCR missing message]

Answer (score 5):

Like @RiggsFolly said in another answer, to fix this go to this [wamp page](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) and scroll down to bottom most section and download **All VC Redistribuable Packages**. These zip files contain five 32 bit & 64 bit VC installers.

If you have 64bit wamp, install both 32 & 64 bit setups. Otherwise 32 bit would be enough. In some cases only latest version would be sufficient, but some times you might have to install all of them, one by one.

[image]

Comment: And in particular, the WAMPserver install needs MSVCR110.dll in both \Windows\SysWOW64 and \Windows\System32 (or at least I had to copy it into System32 but I didn't check back to see if I could then delete from SysWOW64.. it worked, enough...)

Answer (score 3):

If you check on the [WAMPServer Forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2) there is a document called [WAMPServer 3 All you need to know](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

In that document there is a link to the [Secondary repository of Wampserver files](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

In there, if you scroll to the bottom of the page you will find a link to an installer which will install all the possible required MSVC C/C++ runtime libraries that any version of Apache that WAMPServer can have installed might possibly need called 
`Microsoft VC++ packages VC2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017 zip files`

Click the link that matches the WAMPServer you have installed, 32bit or 64bit and run the installer.

For some unknown reason, Microsoft keep messing with the pages that are supposed to link to their downloads of these libraries, and ending up with broken links. V Annoying

Also remember that if you are using the WAMPSevrer 64bit you need to install BOTH the 32bit and 64bit versions of these MSVC Runtimes.